# Why is the dart formatter not properly formatting a file?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my [bottom_nav_layout package](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_nav_layout), I am [losing 10 pub points](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_nav_layout/score) because of the dart formatting. pub.dev says:

```
"lib/src/page_stack.dart doesn't match the Dart formatter."
```

The error message can be found here. However, when I run `dart format .` or `flutter format .`, the [offending file](https://github.com/m-azyoksul/bottom_nav_layout/blob/main/lib/src/page_stack.dart) is not changed.

```
"... Unchanged lib\src\page_stack.dart ..."
```

How to solve this problem?

flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: What version of Dart are you using to do the formatting? When I format the code (with Dart 2.14.4), there are several changes. You can try use https://dartpad.dev to format the code using the most recent released version of Dart.

Comment: I tried it. It only divided the following line into 3 lines: `this..remove(pageIndex)..remove(pageIndex);`. So is this because my dart formatter is outdated? How can I fix that?

Comment: Please start by telling me what version your Dart installation is right now. Also, I expect your Dart installation comes from your Flutter installation? If so, you just need to update Flutter to latest version.

Comment: I have ` flutter: ">=1.17.0"` in my yaml file. Should I update it? Will people with a lower flutter version be able to use this package?

Comment: I don't talk about what you have in your YAML file. Pleas post the output of running: `flutter doctor`. But yeah, it seems like you might have a very old version of Flutter since your project is not even updated to Flutter 2.x.x. Any particular reason for wanting to have your project to support Flutter 1.17.0?

Comment: Ok. In flutter doctor output, I have `[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239357/discussion-between-m-azyoksul-and-julemand101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dart formatter changed the rules for cascades in Dart 2.14 with the following change which makes the formatter to always split the cascade in case of multiple cascades: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/1006

This explains why there are a difference in how your code is formatted when using Dart 2.13 (or older) comparing to latest version (Dart 2.14.x).

So if you want the maximum of points on pub.dev, you need to use Dart 2.14 or later, to do the formatting, since pub.dev are using the new formatting rules for cascades when checking if your code is well-formatted.